# Voltage divider and ADC

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, divider

I have been designing an adjustable voltage regulator using an LT1965 and DAC signal from a microcontroller as shown in the following picture. The output voltage is regulated between 1.8 and 5V using 0..3.3V DAC signal.

[image]

The adjustment is working great without any issue. To measure the output voltage I placed a secondary voltage divider. I set the voltage regulator to 3.3V and measured a voltage at the node between R5 and R6, showing the expected 1.65V. However, when I connect the node between R5 and R6 to an analog input of the microcontroller, the voltage suddenly drops to around 1V and becomes extremely unstable.

This problem is not programming-based, since when I connect the output voltage (when the output voltage is set below the maximum acceptable voltage of ADC - 3.3V) directly to the ADC, everything is running without any issue.

Would anyone be able to point out my problem?

Comment: You need a buffer

Comment: Do you have an output capacitor of at least 10uF (probably several times that if ceramic)??

Comment: Which MCU, which pin, how you initialize it and how do you read it?

Comment: So it goes unstable when you try to control the DAC from the ADC, but works fine if you let it run open loop?

Comment: What is the hold time for the ADC input?

Answer (score 0):

It is your measuring sensor, its resistance is to high.  If you change the values to maybe 10K it should work OK. The minimum input impedance on the Arduino is 10K, anything higher causes errors. You can add maybe a 100nF to the divider to keep it stable. If I guessed the wrong micro check its appropriate data sheet for the correct value. Many microprocessor multiplex inputs to the A/D. There is some internal capacitance that will hold the last reading until it is blead away or changed with a new input. If you do not allow enough time you will start to get unsteady readings when the adjacent pins are of a different voltage.

Comment: I am aware of these issues, but I feel like my problem lies a bit deeper.  Even using 4.7k resistors and 100nF, when I power up the microcontroller (ATSAMD21E18A) I am getting readings that vary in about 0.2V after each startup. Meaning when I connect the MCU to power, once I read 3.2V and the other time I can read 3.4V.

Comment: I have been assuming the reference for the A/D is stable, apparently it may not be.  Monitor that and check your turn on time, the power may be coming up to slow or your code is running before it is stable.